# Posted a job on Elance, can I link to it?

Tags: discussion

I posted a job on Elance to see if I can solve the problem posted in Webmasters ([here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24939/garbage-at-end-of-wordpress-link-in-facebook)).

In the *webmasters* question or comments, can I link to the Elance job?

Comment: Probably not. I do not have a proper source, however. Plus your link to Elance is broken.

Comment: If you want to hire a developer, we have [a site for that](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: What's up with the down votes?   Is this not a valid question for meta?  I thought this is where this type of questions were supposed to be asked.

Comment: @Joao On meta downvotes mean disagreement. In this case you can interpret them as people saying "no, you can't link to your job ad".

Comment: @AnnaLear, downvotes bring the reputation down and downvotes for disagreement means that your rep will go down even if the question is valid. This discourages from asking valid questions, correct?

Comment: @Joao Sure, but reputation on meta isn't hugely important. I guess you could look at it as a measure of how much the community agrees with your ideas and responses, so a low reputation corresponding to downvotes from disagreements still makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say no, don't link to an Elance job from a question on any Stack Exchange site.  You shouldn't even need to link to another Q&A site, bulletin board, or forum for supporting information (unless your question is specifically *about* one of those things).  A question you post here should be complete and self-contained.

As for posting job links in comments, I'd have say I'm against that too.  Stack Overflow isn't a job board, and if we allow people to post a question with an Elance link in the comments, then the question will just be an excuse to post a job ad.  This site is for programming questions between programmers, not employers looking for workers.  If a link isn't essential to the question, just leave it out.

Answer (score -3):

> In the webmasters question or comments, can I link to the Elance job?

Offers of payment for questions are generally frowned upon on SE, for various reasons. I wouldn't put it directly into the question - it could be reason for some to downvote, closevote, or edit it out.

However, I see absolutely nothing wrong with posting an elance link in a comment.

Comment: If anybody gives you flak over an elance link in a comment, and you need support arguing, let me know.

Comment: Tx for the support!

Comment: I'm trying, but I can't think of a valid reason for posting a job ad in the comments to a question.

Comment: @Bill I don't see what's wrong with mentioning that the issue in question is up as an elance job? Of course, the job has to be related to the question, that goes without saying.

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm What would be the purpose behind mentioning that the question is also an elance job?  If it doesn't provide additional information towards finding an answer, then it's just an ad.  (Note that this is something different from an official bug report or jsfiddle link, which I think do enhance questions.)

Comment: @Bill posting an elance link implicitly says, "hey, if this is too difficult (or too localized) to solve on a community basis, I have posted a job here in case anybody wants to give it a shot." It's unusual and I personally have no interest in this kind of job offer, but I don't see what's *wrong* with it really.

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm Wouldn't either of those reasons indicate that the question should be closed?

Comment: @Bill in most cases, probably yes. From which it follows that the question shouldn't have been asked in the first place... in that, I totally agree with your answer. still, if a newbie does this after being told it's too localized a question, I don't see the problem in them posting the link.

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm I wouldn't hold it against a newb for doing that once, but I also wouldn't want people asking questions that they know are going to get closed just so they can post a link to their elance project.  (I recognize that this is a slippery slope argument, but I think it would become a real concern if we allowed it.)  I think we need to draw a line on linking to external resources in questions at what's immediately relevant and adds value.

Comment: @Bill fair enough. You're probably right.