# Is it appropriate to include an eLance link of someone who helped you self-answer a question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, attribution

I recently came across [a question which was self-answered by the author after consulting with an individual outside of StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998691/wpf-adorner-with-controls-inside/10034274#10034274). This seems alright, and the author included enough information in his answer to be useful to future readers.

However, what I questioned was the use of an eLance link to give credit to the individual who helped the author. [Previous meta discussions seemed to establish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120007/posted-a-job-on-elance-can-i-link-to-it) that the inclusion of eLance links for paid support to answer questions were inappropriate, however, none touched on using it to credit outside help.

I took the previous discussions as precedence and I flagged the answer. However, after reading a moderator's flag note I edited out the eLance link; switching instead to a LinkedIn profile<sup>1</sup> so as to not lose the intent of attribution.

When receiving outside help--perhaps in parallel to help on SE--is it appropriate to provide links to eLance profiles of the individuals who "solved" your problem?

<sub>1. I'm not sure if this was the best approach, but it seemed akin to a link to a blog.</sub>

Comment: Woot!  I'm working on a proto with adorners; now I don't have to go looking for that question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's harmless.  I see no difference between an answer with a link to a ref and an answer with a link to a forum/etc. **As long as the answer is self-sufficient, attribution with a link is fine**.. If the answer *depends* upon the link (for the full explanation), then you're doing it wrong--**answers should be self-sufficient**. Of course, this rule does not hold if the link/ref is huge--in this case, give a condensed version and leave a ref.

Edit:Oh, I see that it was a link to a profile, not to an other-forum-answer as I expected. Nope, there's no real need to do that, though, again, it's harmless.

Comment: My only issue with the link to the profile was that it was a link to a pay-for-services profile (eLance). Twitter/email/etc, I probably would have ignored.

Comment: @six IMO its still harmless, but I think the community would prefer it to be unlinked.

Comment: @six I don't think the nature of the profile should make a difference to us - the link was not posted to *advertise*. I would also not edit the link. What if it's not his LinkedIn profile in the first place? Also, we have *loads* of links pointing to paid services in one way or other, e.g. product recommendations.